# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and char pointer to float pointer cast

Tags: iphone, c++

I'm currently writing a file loader for an ipad program and I'm getting strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions. Here is a short snipped of code that I think is the reason for the error:

```
float testFloat() {
    char mem[32];
    char *charPtr = &mem[0];
    float *floatPtr = (float*)(charPtr + 1);
    float f = *floatPtr; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    return f;
}
```

The error happens only if the offset of charPtr is not divisible by 4, so I guess it could have something to do with pointer alignment on ARM CPUs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, this is due to pointer alignment. On many RISC systems, the alignment needs to be at least as large as the data-type itself. (ARM falls into this category.)

In this case, `float` is 4 bytes, so the address needs to be aligned to 4 bytes. (divisible by 4)

<strike>Furthermore, this type of type-punning violates strict-aliasing.</strike>

On x86 systems, memory accesses do not always have to be aligned - but there will usually be a performance penalty on a misaligned access.

Comment: `char*` and `unsigned char*` are exempt from the strict-aliasing rule, so this particular piece of code doesn't violate it.

Comment: @ildjarn: You're right. I forgot you can alias with `char`. Will fix answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will use some memcpy's then. I still find this error kind of strange, isn't the compiler obliged to generated working binary for this snipped? Or does it violate some rule?

Comment: The compiler can't for a number of reasons. Suppose you tried to do `*(float*)(charPtr + 1)` and `*(float*)(charPtr + 2)`. They are offset by only 1 byte. So it's impossible for both of them to be aligned. Also, the alignment of `charPtr` can't always set at compile time. So it's a fundamental problem which you just have to be careful of.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to memory misalignment.
The arm processor has issues with it.

Found this solution,
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/18183

Instead of

```
float *floatPtr = (float*)(charPtr + 1);
float f = *floatPtr; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
return f;
```

Use

```
float f;
unsigned char* pData = (charPtr + 1);
memcpy( &f, pData, sizeof( float ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
struct MyStruct
{
char* _charPtr;
float* _floatPtr;
};

MyStruct myStruct = &mem[0];

float f = *(myStruct._floatPtr);
```

Would it violate the pointer alignment requirement?
Not sure, but worth a try.

Comment: That doesn't even compile.  Did you mean `union` instead of `struct`?  And even if you make that change, it still doesn't compile.